# nav bar issue in IE7 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have clicked on just about every link on the internet regarding this (quite common it seems) problem, yet I cannot find a way to make this work.

Old IE7 is the culprit once again. My dropdown menu floats to the right when it should stay underneath the link it originates from (and does, in IE8+ and Chrome, safari, FF etc).

I can alter this, by changing position to 'relative' but then once you hover over the link and the dropdown appears, the other links in the main nav menu shift to the right, and onto another line!

Here's the necessary code. HTML first...

```
<div id="link_bar">
    <ul>
<li>League Info
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="team_directory.php">Team Directory</a></li>
                <li><a href="fixtures.html">Fixtures</a></li>
                <li><a href="league_rules.html">Rules</a></li>
                <li><a href="public_umpires.php">Umpire Directory</a></li>


            </ul>
        </li>
```

And the CSS ;

```
#link_bar {position: absolute ; 
top: 2em ; 
right: 1em ; 
background: white ; 
width: 40em ; height: 2em
}

#link_bar ul {list-style-type: none ; 
display: inline-table ; 
z-index:11 ; 
margin:1em 1em 1em 0}

#link_bar li {float: left ; 
text-align: left ; 
padding: 0 0.8em 0 0.6em
}

#link_bar ul ul {display: none}
#link_bar ul li:hover > ul {display: block}
#link_bar ul li:hover > ul li {color: black}
#link_bar ul li:hover > ul li a {background: none
#link_bar ul:after {content: "" ; clear:both ; display:block}
#link_bar ul ul {position: absolute ;  
top: 1em  ; 
color: white ; 
width: 10em ; 
padding-top: 1em ; 
margin-left:0
}
#link_bar ul ul li {float:none ; position: relative ; padding: 1em 1em 1em 0}
#link_bar ul ul li {width:100%}
```

Comment: May I ask why do you need to support IE7? Even Facebook doesn't support it since 2011, Google doesn't even support IE __9__ since last year.

Comment: I concur with previous comment - generally we ensure IE7 functions but we have given up on perfection - it just does not justify the investment in our time. Plus IE7 users must be pretty used to sites not looking perfect these days

Comment: You're both right. Feels good not having to worry about it anymore. Its only because our work computers, plus my girlfriend's laptop both have it, but then she uses chrome and we do at work too so no wonder IE is out of date. Thanks